# How to write a Unit testing for Azure Function app?

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, mstest, .net-core-3.1

I have an azure function based on .Net core 3.1. It triggers when a file is uploaded into the Azure Blob Container, processes the CSV file and updates the database

Below is the code excerpt

**FileTrigger.cs**

```
namespace aspnetcore_azurefun_blob
{
    [StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")]
    public class FileTrigger
    {
        #region Property
        private readonly IFileProcessor fileProcessor;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public FileTrigger(IFileProcessor fileProcessor)
        {
            this.fileProcessor = fileProcessor;
        }
        #endregion

        [FunctionName("FileTrigger")]
        public void ProcessFilesFromSamplesContainer([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Function: ProcessFilesFromSamplesContainer is called");
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

            var result = fileProcessor.ProcessAsync(myBlob, name, log, context);

            log.LogInformation($"Function Completed {result.Result} on {DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()} @ {DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}.\n.");
        }
    }
}
```

**FileProcessor.cs**

```
namespace ClientCore.Processor
{
    public interface IFileProcessor
    {
        Task<string> ProcessAsync(Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context);
    }

    public class FileProcessor : IFileProcessor
    {
        #region Property
        private readonly IFileProcessingServiceFacade fileProcessingService;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public FileProcessor(IFileProcessingServiceFacade fileProcessingService)
        {
            this.fileProcessingService = fileProcessingService;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public async Task<string> ProcessAsync(Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            var processingResult = fileProcessingService.ProcessAsync(myBlob, name, log, context);

            return await Task.FromResult($"{processingResult.Result}");
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

**FileProcessingService.cs**

```
namespace BusinessService.Services
{
    public interface IFileProcessingServiceFacade
    {
        Task<string> ProcessAsync(Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context);
    }

    partial class FileProcessingServiceFacade : IFileProcessingServiceFacade
    {
        #region Public Methods
        public async Task<string> ProcessAsync(Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            // Get the Contents from the CSV File
            var csvData = GetCSVData(myBlob);

            AppDbContext.FileRecords.Add(new FileRecords
            {
                FileName = name,
                IsCompleted = DefaultValues.IsCompleted
            });
            AppDbContext.SaveChanges();

            log.LogInformation($"Reading configuration from the configuration settings file: {Configurator.AzureSQLServerConfigurator.ConnnectionString}");
            log.LogInformation("Database is updated..!");

            return await Task.FromResult($"success");
        }
        #endregion

    }

    partial class FileProcessingServiceFacade : ServiceBase<FileProcessingServiceFacade>
    {
        #region Constructor
        public FileProcessingServiceFacade(AppDbContext appDbContext, IOptions<AppConfigurator> configurator) 
            : base(appDbContext, configurator) { }
        #endregion

        #region Extract Data from CSV
        protected static List<dynamic> GetCSVData(Stream jobData)
        {
            try
            {
                #region CsvHelper Mapping and Conversion
                var csvHelperConfig = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                {
                    NewLine = Environment.NewLine,
                    PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToUpper().Replace(" ", ""),
                    HasHeaderRecord = true
                };
                using var reader = new StreamReader(jobData);
                using var csvHelper = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                csvHelper.Context.RegisterClassMap<StudentDetailsMap>();
                var csvHelperRrecords = csvHelper.GetRecords<StudentDetails>()
                    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Name))
                    .OrderBy(x => x.ID);

                return csvHelperRrecords.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

How to write a Unit testing for the above Azure Function app? Just a head start is required.

Comment: Simple example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64464597/5233410